# Cycles Rendering Engine is only rendering a black screen

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I'm having an issue where the whole scene is set up, with maybe a few tweaks left. I have Cycles selected to render the scene. When the render is processing, instead of processing the image, it renders a black screen.

Here's the .blend file [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ground object is set to be hidden for render.
To fix this, open an outliner window:
[image: oultiner]
then click the greyed camera icon.
[image: click camera]